Browser Not Prefilling Saved Credentials on Localhost Until Click in Login Fields
I'm developing a web application on localhost and testing it in Brave browser. I've noticed that the saved username and password fields in the login form do not pre-fill automatically when the page is loaded. The credentials only appear after I click inside one of the form fields (username or password).
This issue doesn't occur when running the application on the remote server; the credentials are prefilled as expected.
Is there a way to make the browser pre-fill the saved credentials on page load when running the app on localhost? This is crucial for my debugging and development process. I guess this is probably a simple fix, but I haven't been able to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated!

the browser may not prompt for you to save the password if set to localhost or to a domain without a CA verified SSL cert.  You might try setting/saving that login manually...  (options section of browser, find password manager settings)  Make sure this is not a real login as a malicious site/app might possibly find a way to get at these credentials....

The thing is the username and password are saved in the browser. They even auto populate as soon as I click inside a given field and select the suggested credentials. But they do not get populated automatically when the page reloads (without clicking into one of the fields)

Are you sure they are saved for that particular domain?  I'm guessing the "suggested" login is one it remembers but is not explicitly saved for that domain.

I think you might be headed in the right direction, since the localhost:4200 redirects to localhost:7013 for login and stores the credentials against the latter domain. But it should still auto fill when I open localhost:7013, right? Also, this is a new profile I have created for testing so no other passwords are saved against this domain.

I'm not sure, but as far as origin goes localhosts with different ports are considered separate domains.

Well designed browsers often have special treatment for localhost and loopback addresses. You should contact the vendor, or possibly reopen this inquiry -> https://community.brave.com/t/saving-localhost-password/486417
